# How to create dynamic Labels and populate them in python 3 tkinter/ttk

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to display the number of logical CPU's in a machine. Since they are of varying nature, how can I achieve this dynamically?

i.e My system can have just 1 logical cpu(can be found in proc/stat/ file) where as someone else might have 4. I want to create Labels for each Logical Cpu present  on a particular system and display it's details on my GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create them the way you create any other object:

```
for i in range(number_of_cpus):
    label = tk.Label(parent, text="CPU #ts" % i)
    label.pack()
```

If you need to reference them later (such as to update the text), you can save a reference in a list or dictionary:

```
labels = []
for i in range(number_of_cpus):
    label = tk.Label(...)
    ...
    labels.append(label)
...
for label in labels:
    label.configure(...)
```